# Ember Render Different View for First Item in Index Model

Tags: ember.js, model, handlebars.js

I am still pretty new to Ember and trying to get my head around it. What I am trying to do is return my model to the index view, which contains, say, 5 array entries. I want my Index view to take the first, to render a separate, featured, view then take the remaining four and render them as a list. However, I have not had any luck with `{{#if @first}}...{{/if}}`like I have read. Here is my code currently:

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     {{#each model as |movie|}}
        {{component (if @first 'featured' 'preview') movie=movie}}
     {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="preview">
    <article class="featured">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="lib/img/feature/{{movie.full}}" alt="{{movie.title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{{movie.preview}}}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="featured">
    <article class="featured">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="lib/img/feature/{{movie.full}}" alt="{{movie.title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{{movie.preview}}}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</script>
```

**Routes.js**

```
var projects = [];
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params) {
            var url = 'lib/js/data/data.json';

            return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
                projects = data;

                return projects.reverse();
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you should create component for displaying items ( two components )

2) use `component` keyword and pass component name depends on index inside each loop ( [Read more at api page](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component) )

```
  {{#each model as |movie|}}
        {{component (if @first 'component-to-display-first-item' 'component-to-display-item') movie=movie}}
   {{/each}}
```

All you need - create two components ( or single one and pass some param which will switch template )

Comment: Could you show me an example? I don't entirely follow.

Comment: @Yuschick you don't use ember-cli?

Comment: I do not. Should I? What does it offer?

Answer (score 0):

You could separate out a `movie-box` component, with this code:

```
{{#if isFeatured}}
  <section class="featured-section">
    <div class="content-container">
      <article class="featured">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="lib/img/feature/{{movie.full}}" alt="{{movie.title}}">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{{movie.preview}}}</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
{{else}}
<article>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="lib/img/preview/{{movie.thumb}}" alt="{{movie.title}}">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>{{movie.title}} ({{movie.year}})</h2>
    <p>{{{movie.preview}}}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{{/if}}
```

... and then, you can invoke it like so:

```
{{#each model as |movie index|}}
  {{movie-box
    movie=movie
    index=index}}
{{/each}}
```

You're passing in the index to the `movie-box` component here, and the `movie-box` component uses a flag `isFeatured` to show the right content, so we should create a computed property on the `movie-box` component's Javascript. Something like this:

```
App.MovieBox = Ember.Component.extend({
  isFeatured: Ember.computed.equal('index', 1)
});
```

In this case, `isFeatured` will return `true` only when the index you pass in is 1, so it will work the right way.

--

You can [learn more about computed properties here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html). Also, you should (later) look at [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/): it makes creating ember apps a lot easier.